# Replace looping error

Tags: python

I am trying to utilize a loop that adds a period to sentences I have added to a .txt file.
However, every time I run the loop, I see that my result ends with the code adding a period every time.

```
    sentences = input_file.read()
    matches = re.finditer("('The dog is happy",sentences,re.MULTILINE)
    if matches:
    for match in matches:
        temp_match = match[1]
        sentences = sentences.replace(temp_match, temp_match + '.')
    output_file.write(sentences)

    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

An example of the error I am getting is this:

```
The dog is happy.
The dog is happy..
The dog is happy...
```

What can I do to stop this loop?

Comment: `file_contents.replace("The dog is happy", "The dog is happy.")`

Comment: `file_contents_v2 = file_contents` does _not_ make a separate copy of the file contents.  Both names refer to the _same_ value.

Comment: Why do you need a regex to add periods to the end of a string?

Comment: Can you please show your input file and what you're getting vs what you expect?

Comment: My bad, the regex was for a different project I was working on. I realize my variables made it confusing, so I tidied things up.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't caring that you've already added a period. It finds the text before any period, then replaces it with the same thing, plus a period, therefore accumulating periods in each iteration

How about you read the lines of the file, check if they end in a period already, then if not, just add it?

```
with open("in.txt") as input_file, open("out.txt") as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.rstrip().endswith("."):
            output_file.write(line.rstrip() + r".\n")
        else:
            output_file.write(line)
```

If you really need the regex, check it within the loop over the lines. No need to `finditer`